# Woocommerce product description in reports table & stock page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, woothemes

Is there is a visual hook or a way to include the product description under the product name in the table below or even instead of showing the product name only, to show the product name and product description.

https://snipboard.io/1Lw6CE.jpg

also if its possible to achieve the same here in the table of stocks below:

https://snipboard.io/ASBtMG.jpg

I will appreciate the help in here, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
function woocommerce_report_update_title_desc_reports($title, $post){
global $current_screen;
if( $current_screen->id == 'woocommerce_page_wc-reports' && is_admin() ) :
    if( is_numeric($post) && get_post_type($post) == 'product' ) :
        $product = wc_get_product($post);
        $title .= ' &mdash; ' . $product->get_short_description(); //$product->get_description();
    elseif( is_object($post) ) : //Check Is Product
        $title .= ' &mdash; ' . $post->get_short_description(); //$product->get_description();
    endif;
endif; //Endif  
return $title;  
}

add_filter('the_title', 'woocommerce_report_update_title_desc_reports', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_name', 'woocommerce_report_update_title_desc_reports', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Works great thank you so much you saved my life, but need your help in a little thing. we need it to work for the vendors, so how can we replace the `is_admin` to work for the vendors too as it appears only for the admin, we removed it still didn;t work because the current screen id is different too. we use woocommerce product vendors plugin for the vendors, so how can we define it to work both for admin and for the vendors with their current screen.

Comment: If current screen id is different then you may update that as per your requirements, and about `is_admin` condition that you may update with `current_user_can` whatever role vendor have and for which role you want to do this or remove `is_admin` that won't be any problem because current screen id condition is there, `is_admin` I put to check that admin screen only so that could be remove as per your needs, let me know if you need further help, Thank you!

Comment: Thats great sir, but how can i know the session is i tried to identify but could't, can be matched with a part of url if i cant define session id ?

Comment: @MagedMohamed See there will a specific role of user for vendor plugin so you may check that role with the help of `current_user_can` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/ and in addition to here is some role bifurcation given from vendor plugin -  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-vendors/ please check and let me know if you need further help for this, this won't need any session or session id just you may check the logged in user role/capabilities based on that you may code it

Comment: yes i got your point sir, but this will result in changing the product name in the products tab in the backend too and any page that has a product name, and we want it to be changed only in the reports tab, you got me ? and thank you for your help

Comment: That's why I put that current screen id condition which only used for reports page only, do you know what I mean? that is important to limit the pages for this changes of product title so it will only apply to specific screen of admin

Comment: yes sir, i got your point, my question is how can i identify the session id of other plugins that uses the report pages too like the product vendors here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-vendors/